# CheckBox color change for api less than 21

Tags: java, android, kotlin, checkbox, android-checkbox

I have a checkbox for which i need to change the color on checked state programmetically.

For api >= 21,
I can change with

`buttonTintList = ColorStateList(arrayOf(intArrayOf(-android.R.attr.state_checked), intArrayOf(android.R.attr.state_checked)), intArrayOf(Color.WHITE, color))`

But for api < 21 ,
I couldn't find any method. Is there any way to change color programmetically for api<21.
Also view should be checkbox, it shouldn't be appcompatcheckbox view.

Comment: i know this isn't what you'd like to hear, but at this point providing support for anything below api 23 is probably an unnecessary chore, you should perhaps consider moving away from below 21 and towards 23 or up

Comment: thank u for response. will think about it

Answer (score 1):

Actually found the answer to change color of checkbox for api < 21.

```
CompoundButtonCompat.getButtonDrawable(compoundButton)?.let {
                DrawableCompat.setTintList(it, getColorStateList(checkedColor = checkColor))
            }
```

This is actually supporting for all api's.